# building 2D datasets from text file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

In scikit-learn, i have to implement a linear SVM classifier on a text documents collection. The documentation on feature extraction shows how to convert only the available datasets, iris, etc. I need to upload my own text file collection and convert it so that it is usable by the estimator. For that, i tried to use this.

```
    fil = datasets.load_files('/home/ayushi/Dropbox/Bundeli/corpus/wob/sklearn',    description=None, categories=None, load_content=True, shuffle=True, encoding='utf-8', charset=None, charset_error=None, decode_error='strict', random_state=0)

    vec = DictVectorizer()
    vec.fit_transform(fil).toarray()
```

Now i get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 143, in fit_transform
return self.transform(X)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 231, in transform
    values.append(dtype(v))
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: gaari
```

Gaari is the name of a genre, something the text needs to be classified into.

Additionally, when i was trying this : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html#example-svm-plot-iris-py

using load_files() to get my own data and following everything exactly, i was getting this error.

```
    TypeError : list indices should be integer not tuples
```

But still, i would have needed to convert it into a 2D dataset. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn.datasets.load_files` only loads files into memory, producing strings, while `DictVectorizer` wants dicts as input. You need a function that does the actual feature extraction:

```
data = datasets.load_files('/home/ayushi/Dropbox/Bundeli/corpus/wob/sklearn',
                           encoding='utf-8')
vec = DictVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(extract_features(f) for f in data.data)
```

where `extract_features` is a dataset-specific function that takes a string and produces a dict mapping feature names to feature values.